# Blocking "Sign-In with Google" iframes using uBlock Origin

Tags: google-oauth, google-sso, ublock-origin

Problem: Google can track me via websites using Google authentication integration on their webpages. Additionally, this popup interrupts my user experience for signing in without Google. How do I effectively get rid of these?

Answer (score 19):

Action: Create a uBlock Origin rule to block these iframes.

Solution:
Add the following to my uBlock Origin filters:

```
||accounts.google.com/gsi/iframe
```

Result: I no longer receive "Sign in with Google" iframe modals/popups.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to expand on the original answer with...

```
||accounts.google.com/gsi/*
```

1. Open uBlock addon from inside the Firefox browser
2. Click tab ['My Filiters'](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Dashboard:-My-filters)
3. Move cursor to a new line (one block per line)
4. Paste above filter on the new line

Following [uBlock's Static network filtering](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax#static-network-filtering) example.

"For all static network filters, ensure that they have as many primary narrowing options as possible, i.e. that they are well targeted. Pure hostname-based filters (such as ||example.com^) are most optimized memory- and cpu-wise." - [uBlock](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Filter-Performance#narrowing-options-for-network-filters)

It was found the previous answer was allowing URL requests from the '/gsi/' subdomain before the '/iframe/' subdomain was blocked. With the revised answer, URL requests (to block) are reduced to one.